# "in/at the same place"

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

> We work in the same place.
> We work at the same place.

Are either OK if the meaning is "We work in/at the same company"?

Comment: In this context "at" is correct for both, but I can't easily put into words exactly why.

Comment: (But "in" is ***also*** "correct" for both, so it doesn't make much difference.)